# Why is this iphone app lagging when I "scroll"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, runtime-error, lag

I am developing a "doodle jump" like game and I have 5 platforms on the screen on at a time. There are two background UIImageViews.  I have the "scrollUp" function, which is called whenever the player is in the top 3/4's of the screen. When the backgrounds are in view, the game slows down and lags, when the backgrounds are out of view (have scolled away), the game runs smooth and fine. I tried disabling the actual code that made them move and it still lagged, the background images are both png's that I created in photoshop and are each in an individual UIImageView.

Here is the "scrollUp" function code: (remember, this is objective-c using Xcode for iphone) :

```
-(void)scrollUp {
    if(fireball.center.y < scrollLine) {
    //sets up variables for background movement to add to.
    float oldXB1 = background1.center.x;
    float oldYB1 = background1.center.y;
    float oldXB2 = background2.center.x;
    float oldYB2 = background2.center.y;

         //makes "players" velocity go in the downward direction (disregard for question)
    velocity.y += .25;

    //sets up a for loop which tests each platform individually
         //[platformHolder] holds all 5 platforms
    for (int i = 0; i < [platformHolder count]; i++) {
    UIImageView *temp = (UIImageView *)[platformHolder objectAtIndex:i];
    if(fireball.center.y > 0) {
        temp.center = CGPointMake(temp.center.x, temp.center.y + 4);
    }
    if(fireball.center.y < 0) {
        temp.center = CGPointMake(temp.center.x, temp.center.y + 8);
        velocity.y += .03;
    }
    if(temp.center.y >  480) {
        scoreNum += 10;
        score.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", scoreNum];
        temp.center = CGPointMake(arc4random() % randomNumMax, 0);
    }
    }

    if(fireball.center.y > 0) {
        background1.center = CGPointMake(oldXB1, oldYB1 + velocityB1.y);
        background2.center = CGPointMake(oldXB2, oldYB2 + velocityB2.y);
    }

    if(fireball.center.y < 0) {
        background1.center = CGPointMake(oldXB1, oldYB1 + velocityB1.y);
        background2.center = CGPointMake(oldXB2, oldYB2 + velocityB2.y);
    }

    if(background1.center.y > (480 + background1.center.y/2)) {
        background1.center = CGPointMake(background1.center.x, -1*background1.center.y );
    }
    if(background2.center.y > (480 + background2.center.y/2)) {
         background2.center = CGPointMake(background2.center.x, -1*background2.center.y );
    }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried drawing the background images on a separate thread?  It's possible that the UIScrollView is trying to update the UI at the same time that you are trying to draw the background.  If they are on the same thread, that could be where the lag is coming from

Comment: I have not, but ill give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Honestly...this is a really bad way of doing this game. You should absolutely look into Cocos2D. ImageViews were not meant for making games with...that way you will get the benefit of OpenGL hardware acceleration and the game will run much much faster.